# How to assign a value to a missing XML node?

Tags: python, xml

I have a function that goes through an XML that is an invoice. The invoice brings the product information, price, quantity, tax code,TariffCode, tax amount and total amount among others.

All the information is loaded without problems by the function. The problem I have is that some product lines come without the tax node so in some lines I am missing the tax stitching data. How can I assign a specific value from 1 to 10 to the tax code in case it does not exist in the product line?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ElectronicInvoice>
<Clave>50618012200310103974900200140010000019937123091972</Clave>
<ActivityCode>151105</ActivityCode>
<NumeroConsecutivo>00200140010000019937</NumeroConsecutivo>
<FechaEmision>2022-01-18T10:56:47-06:00</FechaEmision>
<Emitter>
<NAME>SIGMA , S.A.</Name>
<Identification>
<Type>02</Type>
<Numero>31010556</Numero>
</Identification>
<CommercialName>Sigma </CommercialName>
<Location>
<Province>2</Province>
<Canton>01</Canton>
<District>04</District>
<Borough>11</Borough>
<OtrasSenas>OBLE </OtrasSenas>
</Location>
<Phone>
<CountryCode>111</CountryCode>
</PhoneNumber>24309444</PhoneNumber>
</PhoneNumber>
<Fax>
<CountryCode>111</CountryCode>
<PhoneNumber>24422444</PhoneNumber>
</Fax>
<EmailEmail>ventascosta@ss.com</EmailEmail>
</Sender>
<Receiver>
<FirstName>SI MART</Name>
<Identification>
<Type>01</Type>
<Numero>10944444</Numero>
</Identification>
<CommercialName>SI MART</CommercialName>
<Location>
<Province>1</Province>
<Canton>15</Canton>
<District>01</District>
<Borough>20</Borough>
<OtrasSenas>BOSCO</OtrasSenas>
</Location>
<Phone>
<CountryCode>444</CountryCode>
<NumTelefono>83316454544</NumTelefono>
</PhoneNumber>
<E-mailElectronic>OEL@GMAIL.COM</E-mailElectronic>
</Receiver>
<ConditionSale>01</ConditionSale>
<MeansPayment>01</MeansPayment>
<ServiceDetail>
<LineDetail>
<LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
<Codigo>2118402010700</Codigo>
<CommercialCode>
<Type>01</Type>
<Code>13171</Code>
</CodeCommercialCode>
<CommercialCode>
<Type>03</Type>
<Codigo>7441008941101</Codigo>
</SalesCode>
<Quantity>3</Quantity>
<UnitSize>Unit</UnitSize>
<Detail>PRESSED HAM 125G FUD</Detail>
<UnitPrice>918</UnitPrice>.
<MontoTotal>2754</MontoTotal>
<SubTotal>2754</SubTotal>
<Tax>
<Code>01</Code>
<FeeCode>08</FeeCode>
<Fee>13</Fee>
<Month>358.02</Month>
</Tax>
<NetTax>0</NetTax>
<LineTotalAmount>3112.02</LineTotalAmount>
</LineDetail>
<DetailLine>
<LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
<Codigo>2118403010100</Codigo>
<CommercialCode>
<Type>01</Type>
<Code>13217</Code>
</CodeCommercialCode>
<CommercialCode>
<Type>03</Type>
<Codigo>7441008931904</Codigo>
</SalesCode>
<Quantity>3</Quantity>
<UnitSize>Unit</UnitSize>
<DETAIL>HAMMORTADELA JAMONADA 125G ZUR</Detail>
<UnitPrice>752</UnitPrice>.
<MontoTotal>2256</MontoTotal>
<SubTotal>2256</SubTotal>
<Tax>
<Code>01</Code>
<TariffCode>02</TariffCode>
<Rate>1</Rate>
<Month>22.56</Month>
</Tax>
<NetTax>0</NetTax>
<LineTotalAmount>2278.56</LineTotalAmount>
</LineDetail>
<DetailLine>
<LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
<Codigo>2399501009900</Codigo>
<CommercialCode>
<Type>01</Type>
<Code>13746</Code>
</CodeCommercialCode>
<CommercialCode>
<Type>03</Type>
<Codigo>7441014703502</Codigo>
</SalesCode>
<Quantity>4</Quantity>
<UnitSize>Unit</UnitSize>
<Detail>CHEESE SAUCE 180G DPR</Detail>
<UnitPrice>864</UnitPrice>.
<MontoTotal>3456</MontoTotal>
<SubTotal>3456</SubTotal>
<Tax>
<Code>01</Code>
<FeeCode>08</FeeCode>
<Fee>13</Fee>
<Month>449.28</Month>
</Tax>
<NetTax>0</NetTax>
<LineTotalAmount>3905.28</LineTotalAmount>
</LineDetail>
<DetailLine>
<LineNumber>4</LineNumber>
<Codigo>2118403010200</Codigo>
<CommercialCode>
<Type>01</Type>
<Code>14401</Code>
</CodeCommercialCode>
<CommercialCode>
<Type>03</Type>
<Codigo>7441008933915</Codigo>
</SalesCode>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<UnitSize>Unit</UnitSize>
<Detail>SALCHICHA AHUMADA 500G ZUR</Detail>
<UnitPrice>1273</UnitPrice>.
<MontoTotal>1273</MontoTotal>
<SubTotal>1273</SubTotal>
<Tax>
<Code>01</Code>
<TariffCode>02</TariffCode>
<Rate>1</Rate>
<Month>12.73</Month>
</Tax>
<NetTax>0</NetTax>
<LineTotalAmount>1285.73</LineTotalAmount>
</LineDetail>
<DetailLine>
<LineNumber>5</LineNumber>
<Codigo>2118403010100</Codigo>
<CommercialCode>
<Type>01</Type>
<Code>14403</Code>
</CodeCommercialCode>
<CommercialCode>
<Type>03</Type>
<Codigo>7441008932086</Codigo>
</SalesCode>
<Quantity>2</Quantity>
<UnitSize>Unit</UnitSize>
<Detail>MORTADELA SIN TOCINO 500G ZUR</Detail>.
<UnitPrice>940</UnitPrice>.
<MontoTotal>1880</MontoTotal>
<SubTotal>1880</SubTotal>
<NetTax>0</NetTax>
<MontoTotalLine>1898.8</MontoTotalLine>
</LineDetail>
<DetailLine>
<LineNumber>6</LineNumber>
<Codigo>2118403010200</Codigo>
<CommercialCode>
<Type>01</Type>
<Code>14493</Code>
</CodeCommercialCode>
<CommercialCode>
<Type>03</Type>
<Codigo>7441008934035</Codigo>
</SalesCode>
<Quantity>3</Quantity>
<UnitSize>Unit</UnitSize>
<Detail>Chicken sausage ZURQU 500 GR</Detail>
<UnitPrice>1047</UnitPrice>.
<MontoTotal>3141</MontoTotal>
<SubTotal>3141</SubTotal>
<Tax>
<Code>01</Code>
<TariffCode>02</TariffCode>
<Rate>1</Rate>
<Month>31.41</Month>
</Tax>
<NetTax>0</NetTax>
<LineTotalAmount>3172.41</LineTotalAmount>
</LineDetail>
<DetailLine>
<LineNumber>7</LineNumber>
<Codigo>2118100000200</Codigo>
<CommercialCode>
<Type>01</Type>
<Code>405219</Code>
</CodeCommercialCode>
<CommercialCode>
<Type>03</Type>
<Codigo>7441008937036</Codigo>
</SalesCode>
<Quantity>3</Quantity>
<UnitSize>Unit</UnitSize>
<Detail>TOCINETA 200 G ZURQUI</Detail>
<UnitPrice>1260</UnitPrice>.
<MontoTotal>3780</MontoTotal>
<SubTotal>3780</SubTotal>
<NetTax>0</NetTax>
<MontoTotalLine>4271.4</MontoTotalLine>
</LineDetail>
</ServiceDetail>
<InvoiceSummary>
<CurrencyTypeCode>
<CodeCurrency>CRC</CodeCurrency>
<ExchangeType>1</ExchangeType>
</CodeCurrencyType> </CodeTypeCurrency>
<TotalServGravings>0</TotalServGravings>
<TotalServExemptServices>0</TotalServExemptServices>
<TotalGravagedTrades>18540</TotalGravagedTrades>
<TotalExemptTotalRanks>0</TotalExemptTotalRanks>
<TotalGravaged>18540</TotalGravaged>
<TotalExemptTotal>0</TotalExemptTotal>
<TotalSales>18540</TotalSales>
<TotalSalesNet>18540</TotalSalesNet>
<TotalTax>1384.2</TotalTax>
<TotalInvoiceSummary>19924.2</TotalInvoiceSummary>
</InvoiceSummary>
<Other>
<OtherText code="ROUTE">352</OtherText>
<OtherText code="OC">N/A</OtherText> </OtherText>
<OtherText codecode="SAP DOCUMENT">4418768782</OtherText>
<OtherText code="ORDER">N/A</OtherText>
<OtherText code="REFERENCE">N/A</OtherText>
<OtherText codecode="DELIVERY">N/A</OtherText>
<OtherText code="TIME DELIVERY">000000</OtherText>
<OtherText code="DELIVERY CODE">10145081</OtherText>
<OtroTexto codigo="DELIVERY ADDRESS1">OLMAN ELIZONDO ESPINOZA</OtroTexto>
<OtroTexto codigo="ADRESS DELIVERY2">VARGAS ARAYA</OtroTexto>
<OtherText code="DELIVERY ADDRESS3">MONTES DE OCA,SJ</OtherText>
<OtherText codecode="VENDORNUMBER">N/A</OtherText>
<OtherText code="ORDERNUMBER">N/A</OtherText>
<OtherText codecode="STORENUMBER">N/A</OtherText>
<OtroTexto codigo="NUMEROGLN">0000000000000</OtroTexto>
<OtherText codecode="DATEORDER">0000-00-00</OtherText>
<OtherText codecode="NUMERORECEPTION">N/A</OtherText>
<OtroTexto codigo="DECHADOCUMENTORECEPCION">2022-01-18</OtroTexto>
<OtherText code="TOTALDISCOUNTDISCOUNTED">0.000</OtherText>
<OtherText code="TOTALDISCOUNTEXPENSED">0.000</OtherText>
<OtherText code="TOTALDISCOUNTLINE1">0.000</OtherText>
<OtherText code="TOTALDESCUENTOLINEA2">0.000</OtherText>
<OtherText code="TOTALDESCUENTOLINEA3">0.000</OtherText>
<OtherText code="TOTALDESCUENTOLINEA4">0.000</OtherText>
<OtherText code="TOTALDESCUENTOLINEA5">0.000</OtherText>
<OtherText code="TOTALDESCUENTOLINEA6">0.000</OtherText>
<OtherText code="TOTALDESCUENTOLINEA7">0.000</OtherText>
<OtherText code="VAT 1%">85,500</OtherText>
<OtherText code="VAT 13%">1298,700</OtherText>
<OtherText code="SAD">N/A</OtherText>
<OtroTexto codigo="TIPONOTA">N/A</OtroTexto>
</Other>
<ds:Signature Id="Signature">
<ds:SignedInfo Id="Signature-SignedInfo">
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
<ds:Reference URI="">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
<ds:XPath>not(ancestor-or-or-self::ds:Signature)</ds:XPath>
</ds:Transform>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>osb4oZlINhzfMcUWGosifDC8tNh6VStEDj3DmGN8PrY=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference Id="SignedPropertiesID" Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#Signature-SignedProperties">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>Bu9zXYA+SbtMx7L6v6oRSfm7LiP5izYbrPboPsSzsEU=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>

<ds:KeyInfo Id="Certificate1">

</ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:Object Id="Signature-Object">
<xades:QualifyingProperties Target="#Signature">
<xades:SignedProperties Id="Signature-SignedProperties">
<xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
<xades:SigningTime>2022-01-18T11:00:07-06:00</xades:SigningTime>
```

A detail line is the one that does not have the tax code. Would someone recommend me a for to go through the detail line and get the data of each product and when there is no tax node assigns a specific value to the tax code and the TariffCode or feecode.

```
total_tax = 0.0
taxes = []
tax_nodes = line.xpath("inv:Impuesto", namespaces=namespaces)
for tax_node in tax_nodes:
    tax_code = re.sub(r"[^0-9]+", "", tax_node.xpath("inv:Codigo", namespaces=namespaces)[0].text)
    tax_amount = float(tax_node.xpath("inv:Tarifa", namespaces=namespaces)[0].text)
    _logger.debug('FECR - tax_code: %s', tax_code)
    _logger.debug('FECR - tax_amount: %s', tax_amount)

    if product_id and product_id.non_tax_deductible:
        tax = invoice.env['account.tax'].search([('tax_code', '=', tax_code),
                                                 ('amount', '=', tax_amount),
                                                 ('type_tax_use', '=', 'purchase'),
                                                 ('non_tax_deductible', '=', True),
                                                 ('active', '=', True)], limit=1)
    else:
        tax = invoice.env['account.tax'].search([('tax_code', '=', tax_code),
                                                 ('amount', '=', tax_amount),
                                                 ('type_tax_use', '=', 'purchase'),
                                                 ('non_tax_deductible', '=', False),
                                                 ('active', '=', True)], limit=1))
```

Comment: XML is not valid one and has no format. Please add a minimum related version including the missing element.

Comment: Ready the XML is added almost complete

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have a for that goes through an XML of an invoice to be imported to the purchasing part of my system, in the invoice for each product there is a line and in some lines of the product there is the tax node and in others there is no tax node tax. I was able to import all the invoice data without problems, only when the tax node does not exist it leaves the tax cell blank. What I cannot do is that when the XML data is imported and the tax node does not exist, assign a fixed value to the tax cell.